# Unable to deserialize Json using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#

My model:

```
internal class Order
{
    internal string OrderId;
    internal string ShippingId;
    internal Date OrderDate;
    internal double Amount;
}
```

My method that uses `DataContractJsonSerializer` :

```
Order GetOrder(string json)
{
    Order obj;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))  
    {  
        DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Order));  
        obj = (Order) deserializer.ReadObject(ms);  
    }  
    return obj;
}
```

But its not able to deserialize it? I cant understand why its giving me exception always!

Comment: Please add the exception message.

Comment: Can you please show the JSON text?

Comment: The `return obj;` is wrong, `obj` does not exist in this context. In this case you're getting a compilation error.